# Download files from url and save to iCloud (Folder app in iOS 11)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, icloud

I have some file links in url and I just want to give user a option to save those files directly to his/her `iCloud` storage or the latest `Files App` in `iOS 11`.I have not came through any such link which helps me out in this regard. Some links are creating a **zip file** after downloading as `NSData` and syncing to **iCloud**. I want to give a feature like **WhatsApp** to save directly the file withe the same extension to **iCloud**.

Comment: what is your effort?

Comment: I have not came through any such link which helps me out in this regard. Some links are creating a **zip file** after downloading as `NSData` and syncing to **iCloud**. I want to give a feature like **WhatsApp** to save directly the file withe the same extension to **iCloud**.

Comment: put as much details possible in the question to get more response.